# How to send call to JSP from AJAX?

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

This servlet code,here 1st i want to send return message(if message!=null) to the Ajax for alert and 2nd one if message==null i want to call another jsp with pass the list to this jsp.

```
    if(message!=null){
                response.setContentType("text/plain");
                response.getWriter().write(message);
            }else{
                JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
                String urlToRedirect = "SearchEmployee.jsp";
                jobj.put("url",urlToRedirect );
                response.getWriter().write(jobj.toString());
                }
```

Here i cant understand how to call this jsp url in else part

```
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'../SearchEmployeeServlet',

        data:$('#DisplayEmployeeListForm').serialize(),//$('form').serialize();
        success:function(msg){
            if(msg!=""){
                alert(msg);
                window.location.reload(true);
            }else{
                ....here i want to call 2nd jsp

            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just forward the request server-side, to avoid needing the client to make a second request:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("SearchEmployee.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Or alternatively, you could send an HTTP redirect response, so the client should handle the redirection to the second request automatically:

```
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectUrl("SearchEmployee.jsp"));
```

Note that how you handle this in the JavaScript depends on the datatype you expect to receive from `SearchEmployee.jsp`.  For example, if it is XML and you have set the response content-type to `text/xml` jQuery will parse it and pass you an XML DOM object to your `success` function:

```
success:function(msg) {
    if (msg instanceof XMLDocument) {
        // handle list
    } else {
        alert(msg);
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
}
```

If you're expecting HTML, this may be returned as a string, so you could test to see if your returned string starts with some HTML.  For example, if your HTML will always start with a `<ul>` tag:

```
success:function(msg) {
    if (msg.startsWith("<ul>")) { // note you may need to do msg = $.trim(msg) first
        // handle list
    } else {
        alert(msg);
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
}
```

---

If you don't want to auto-forward as suggested above and you'd rather stick with your current approach, there are a few things you'll need to change.

Using `if(msg!="")` in your `success` function is bad as that will return `true` as long as the server does not return an empty response (so in both cases you'll get an alert).

The first thing to do is to add a `content-type` header to your servlet code to indicate you're returning JSON in the second case:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(jobj.toString());
```

Now when jQuery handles the response, it will attempt to parse it as JSON before calling the `success` function.  As such, you can now test in your success function whether the argument jQuery has given you is an object or a string:

```
success:function(msg){
    if (typeof msg === "object") {
        // you got the JSON response
        $.ajax({
            url: msg.url,
            // etc...
        });
    } else {
        // you got the plain text response
        alert(msg);
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @priyankaahire Sorry, I'm not sure I understand that comment.  Regardless, I've edited my answer to explain how to do things the way you're trying to.

Comment: From servlet i want 2 response 1st if alert else jsp call with list..I can't understand  how to do this ...u give me you own suggestion.I will try with that

Comment: @priyankaahire If you want to do it in one request, then you'll need to test the response you get from the server to see whether it was a message to alert or a "list" to handle otherwise.  Doing a `typeof msg` will give you that answer (e.g., `if (typeof msg === 'string') { ... } else { ... }`).

Comment: I've added some more detail about how to check what data has been returned by the server.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the ajax request in else part as you did above.

```
$.ajax({url: "jsp url", success: function(result){

}});
```

Find more information [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

Comment: "result" means, what servlet return i.e url or any thing else because i cant understand if I use this in else part of ajax what i write in servlet.